# wagtail return server error 500 when insert embed

Tags: python, django, wagtail

env:
    Django==1.7.8
    wagtail==0.8.8
execute "manage.py runserver" to launch the website

I copy a example.mp4 file to /static dir, then can open it in browser@127.0.0.1:8000/statice/example.mp4

but when I insert http://127.0.0.1:8000/statice/example.mp4 to page as a embed component, the server return a 500 error.
then I use another internet url, http://viemo.com/86036070, and wagtail still show a 500 error.
the embed url will be send to /admin/embeds/chooser/upload/ 
I decide to review the related source code to find out, but...

top **urls.py**:

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^django-admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

```
url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
url(r'^search/', include(wagtailsearch_urls)),
url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
url('^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap),

url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
```

)

and **admin_usrls**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from wagtail.wagtailadmin.forms import PasswordResetForm
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.views import account, chooser, home, pages, tags, userbar, page_privacy
from wagtail.wagtailcore import hooks

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^$', home.home, name='wagtailadmin_home'),

    url(r'^failwhale/$', home.error_test, name='wagtailadmin_error_test'),

    url(r'^explorer-nav/$', pages.explorer_nav, name='wagtailadmin_explorer_nav'),

    url(r'^pages/$', pages.index, name='wagtailadmin_explore_root'),
    url(r'^pages/(\d+)/$', pages.index, name='wagtailadmin_explore'),

    url(r'^pages/new/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\d+)/$', pages.create, name='wagtailadmin_pages_create'),
    url(r'^pages/new/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\d+)/preview/$', pages.preview_on_create, name='wagtailadmin_pages_preview_on_create'),
    url(r'^pages/usage/(\w+)/(\w+)/$', pages.content_type_use, name='wagtailadmin_pages_type_use'),

    url(r'^pages/(\d+)/edit/$', pages.edit, name='wagtailadmin_pages_edit'),
    url(r'^pages/(\d+)/edit/preview/$', pages.preview_on_edit, name='wagtailadmin_pages_preview_on_edit'),

    url(r'^pages/preview/$', pages.preview, name='wagtailadmin_pages_preview'),
    url(r'^pages/preview_loading/$', pages.preview_loading, name='wagtailadmin_pages_preview_loading'),

    url(r'^pages/(\d+)/view_draft/$', pages.view_draft, name='wagtailadmin_pages_view_draft'),
    url(r'^pages/(\d+)/add_subpage/$', pages.add_subpage, name='wagtailadmin_pages_add_subpage'),
    url(r'^pages/(\d+)/delete/$', pages.delete, name='wagtailadmin_pages_delete'),
    url(r'^pages/(\d+)/unpublish/$', pages.unpublish, name='wagtailadmin_pages_unpublish'),

    url(r'^pages/search/$', pages.search, name='wagtailadmin_pages_search'),

    url(r'^pages/(\d+)/move/$', pages.move_choose_destination, name='wagtailadmin_pages_move'),
    url(r'^pages/(\d+)/move/(\d+)/$', pages.move_choose_destination, name='wagtailadmin_pages_move_choose_destination'),
    url(r'^pages/(\d+)/move/(\d+)/confirm/$', pages.move_confirm, name='wagtailadmin_pages_move_confirm'),
    url(r'^pages/(\d+)/set_position/$', pages.set_page_position, name='wagtailadmin_pages_set_page_position'),

    url(r'^pages/(\d+)/copy/$', pages.copy, name='wagtailadmin_pages_copy'),

    url(r'^pages/moderation/(\d+)/approve/$', pages.approve_moderation, name='wagtailadmin_pages_approve_moderation'),
    url(r'^pages/moderation/(\d+)/reject/$', pages.reject_moderation, name='wagtailadmin_pages_reject_moderation'),
    url(r'^pages/moderation/(\d+)/preview/$', pages.preview_for_moderation, name='wagtailadmin_pages_preview_for_moderation'),

    url(r'^pages/(\d+)/privacy/$', page_privacy.set_privacy, name='wagtailadmin_pages_set_privacy'),

    url(r'^pages/(\d+)/lock/$', pages.lock, name='wagtailadmin_pages_lock'),
    url(r'^pages/(\d+)/unlock/$', pages.unlock, name='wagtailadmin_pages_unlock'),

    url(r'^choose-page/$', chooser.browse, name='wagtailadmin_choose_page'),
    url(r'^choose-page/(\d+)/$', chooser.browse, name='wagtailadmin_choose_page_child'),
    url(r'^choose-external-link/$', chooser.external_link, name='wagtailadmin_choose_page_external_link'),
    url(r'^choose-email-link/$', chooser.email_link, name='wagtailadmin_choose_page_email_link'),

    url(r'^tag-autocomplete/$', tags.autocomplete, name='wagtailadmin_tag_autocomplete'),

    # 登陆
    url(r'^login/$', account.login, name='wagtailadmin_login'),
    url(r'^account/$', account.account, name='wagtailadmin_account'),
    url(r'^account/change_password/$', account.change_password, name='wagtailadmin_account_change_password'),
    url(r'^account/notification_preferences/$', account.notification_preferences, name='wagtailadmin_account_notification_preferences'),
    url(r'^logout/$', account.logout, name='wagtailadmin_logout'),

    url(r'^userbar/(\d+)/$', userbar.for_frontend, name='wagtailadmin_userbar_frontend'),
    url(r'^userbar/moderation/(\d+)/$', userbar.for_moderation, name='wagtailadmin_userbar_moderation'),
]


# This is here to make sure that 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' is reversed correctly
# It must be placed after 'wagtailadmin_login' to prevent this from being used
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
]


# Import additional urlpatterns from any apps that define a register_admin_urls hook
for fn in hooks.get_hooks('register_admin_urls'):
    urls = fn()
    if urls:
        urlpatterns += urls
```

I don't find which view /admin/embeds/chooser/upload/ will be routed to. but I am sure there is a view function map to this url, because I add a "print" in django.forms.forms.is_valid method, and it be triggered.

can anybody help me? thanks in advance, and sorry for my D-level english.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
update:
I create a new wagtail project, and write a simple page model, then I insert a embed to the content field, a RichTextField, the server return OK-200, but nothing was insert to content in edit panel.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
update:
the view for the path is wagtailembeds.views.chooser.chooser_upload. I will check it.
thanks all.

Comment: please post your whole error stacktrace.

Comment: it would be really useful to see the error traceback

Comment: no error stacktrace, the information I got is:

Comment: no error stacktrace, the information I got is: 1. django.forms.forms.is_valid() is called, 2. no error appearence in console and browser, 3. I use tamper data tool to capture req&responce, found that the server return a 500 error. and what confuse me is that which view work for path /admin/embeds/chooser/upload/. i didn't do any modification on wagtail source code. and the source code is available at linuxsoftware/blue-wagtail-site@github.